# Building Lua modules for Lua embedded in Rust (rust-lua53)

Tags: lua, rust, rust-cargo

I'm currently using the [rust-lua53](https://github.com/jcmoyer/rust-lua53) crate to embed Lua into a Rust project.  rust-lua53 downloads and builds the Lua tarball during "cargo build" (in its build.rs).

I'd like to make other Lua libraries (written in C) available to Lua code in my application, eg [LPeg](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/) or [LFS](https://keplerproject.github.io/luafilesystem/), but it's not obvious to me how to do it.

My ideas so far are:

- Build the libraries against a stock Lua and hope I get away with it (or have to check it matches every subsequent rust-lua53 release)
- Somehow expose the relevant headers from rust-lua53 (can a crate include extra files like that?)
- Change to a different Rust/Lua binding which somehow makes this easier.
- Fork rust-lua53 and make it embed the extra libraries I want as well as the plain Lua interpreter.
- Implement the functionality in Rust instead of relying on C libraries.  Plausible for LFS in my application, but re-implementing LPeg is beyond what I want to do right now!

Comment: Compiling the C modules against stock Lua 5.3 (any release) should work fine. If you don't want to rely on separate dynamic libraries, you could link statically and add the relevant `luaopen_*` functions to `package.preload`. `rust-lua53` even seems to have a `preload_library` method for just that ...

Comment: I'd forgotten that Lua is ABI compatible in minor releases, thanks, so the "getting away with it" works. It still seems non-ideal downloading Lua separately in each crate for that though, so I'd be interested in any improvements to the situation.

Comment: On Unixes you only need the public Lua headers (4 files) for building extension modules. You could just add those to your repository. But what do you need the crates for? LFS and LPeg are most likely available in your favorite deb or rpm repository, or you could use LuaRocks or LuaDist to build the Lua extension modules. That's what they are designed for.

Comment: I don't *need* crates, but I thought it might be nice to split those out as more generally useful.

Comment: I like the idea of embedding LuaRocks as a more general solution, but I'm not convinced about using distribution packages. Lua 5.3 isn't that common yet, and I'd prefer not to need the administrator to have to install things.